# SwaggerDiff for Swagger Version 3

Tags: swagger

I recently came across this little tool: [Swagger-diff](https://github.com/Sayi/swagger-diff)

It compares two APIs which are currently running and then shows changes you made from old version to new version. Sadly this only works for Swagger 1.x and 2.0.

Does anyone knows a tool with the same functionality but works with Swagger 3.0?

Regards,
Hannes

Answer (score 2):

Sometime back, I was also challenged with the same issue.
I was not able to find anything readymade open-source online.

But digging all the swagger-diff implementations a little bit deeper, I found that all of them work on this [swagger-parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) library.

Apart from the one you mentioned, there is one implementation in [ruby](https://github.com/civisanalytics/swagger-diff) and another one in [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-diff). All of them work on the same concept of the swagger-parser.

Swagger 3 works on yml instead of JSON format, so the above libraries will fail to parse the contracts. So, you need to modify the [swagger-diif library](https://github.com/Sayi/swagger-diff) to convert the yml to JSON format before parsing. Everything else remains the same.